# Gradle cache growing indefinitely

Tags: gradle

Is there ANY mechanism in gradle cache to delete old snapshot artifacts? Caches on our build servers seem to be growin indefinitely and can take up to several GBs. We continuously build with new snapshot artifacts several times per day and gradle cache seems to be collecting ALL those artifacts. Is there a way to tell Gradle cache to delete all SNAPSHOT artifacts but last one (or few last ones ..)? Thanks.

Matthew

Comment: Which Gradle version are you using?

Comment: I'm using verson 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution now: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home:cache_cleanup

From version 4.10 onwards, Gradle automatically cleans its user home directory. The cleanup runs in the background when the Gradle daemon is stopped or shuts down. If using --no-daemon, it runs in the foreground after the build session with a visual progress indicator.